# My code runs more than one time in the whole Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TankItemScript : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public GameObject tankFollowerPrefab;
    public bool a = true;
    public GameObject laptopPrefab;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            GameObject tank = Instantiate(tankFollowerPrefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - 1.5f), Quaternion.identity, transform);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0.2f, 0f);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        if (a == true)
        {
            Instantiate(laptopPrefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1f, transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
            a = false;
        }
    }
}
```

`void Start()` running 3 times. Even with checking that I running it ONE time.

There is no other scripts that are affecting this script. My laptop prefab is used only in this code.

Why instead of one laptop it spawns 3-4? How to fix it?
The problem is that it's happening not only with this script, but with others too!
Instead of adding 1 to my variable, it adds 3!

Even more, it worked before! I feel that memes become reality D:

Comment: add something like `Debug.Log("Running start from the following object" + transform.gameObject.name);` and see what you get.

Comment: @adnan_e It shows up four times, but sometimes shows up only one time

Comment: apologies in advance for the rant. I get so frustrated by this kinds of posts. Be curious! About your code!! Investigate!!! Is it always the same object? What is the parent? Do they all have the same transform? Remove that object and put it somehere else. rename it. There is so much more data you can gather, instead of stopping at the first sign that the code doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @bolov, Ofc I did this) I tried 4 different ways how to spawn this object. Looked at the parent. Changed parent. Changed conditions of spawn. I tried a lot of things, ofc I can list them, but it just junk. The problem is that this started to happen literally when I closed and opened project

Comment: @AndreiVechar how can it be junk? Every information matters on this weird kind of bug.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that you put this script (with this start function) on more than one object and then every object calls its start function.

Comment: I have only one object of this type on the scene.

Comment: But do you have more objects (of different type) on the scene with the same script on them?

Comment: No. I use this script only for one object.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but have you tried to remove this code from the update method?

Comment: Please only post in English here. If you wish to use Russian, please do so on the dedicated [ru.so] site. But in _either_ language, answers must attempt to answer the question. Once you have earned 50 reputation points [you will be able to add comments for this sort of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Update method just turns my object.